# Perfect forwarding fails when target is aggregate with array

Tags: c++, aggregate, c++14, perfect-forwarding

```
#include <iostream>

struct X2
{
    int i;
    int j;
    char buf[10];
};

X2 glob{1,2,"abc"};    // OK

struct X
{
     X2 x2;

     template<typename... Args>
     X(Args&&... args): x2{args...} {}
};

int main()
{
     X x;                // OK
     X y{1, 2};          // OK
     X z{1, 2, "abc"};   // error
}
```

The last line gives error: `17 : error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]`

If I use `std::forward(args)...` instead of `args...` then even more errors come up; and also there are errors if I try to use `{'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}` as initializer instead of the string literal.

Is there a way to make this work, i.e. allow `X z{......};` where anything inside the braces that would be a legal initializer for `x2`, is accepted and does in fact initialize `x2` ?

Comment: "*Is there a way to make this work"*, remove the constructor, or use `std::string` as the type of `buf`

Comment: writing `'a','b','c','\0'` instead of `"abc"` works with VS using C++17

Answer (score 5):

This is a precarious design issue that was inherited from C++98: Certain conversions or initializations are syntactically restricted to literals, in particular string literals as initializers for char arrays ([dcl.init.string]/1) and integer literals as null pointer constants ([conv.ptr]/1). That, of course, doesn't go well with "perfect" forwarding.

For null pointers, the issue was circumvented by introducing `nullptr`, which can be used instead of `0` and works fine even after being forwarded.

In your case, there are basically two major options:

- Exploit brace elision - `X` is an aggregate, too:

  ```
  struct X {
       X2 x2;
  } z{1, 2, "abc"}; // Ok
  ```
- Declare `buf` to have class type, e.g. `std::string` or, perhaps more appropriate in your case, some statically sized equivalent (limited to size 10).

Comment: sorry, I meant that in general `X` would not be an aggregate, my idea was to allow non-aggregates with a lot of public data to still use aggregate initialization for that public data